# Using paper trail gem with ActiveRecord table_name_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I am currently setting up PaperTrail for my Rails 5 application, where I need custom names for the version tables. As for the basic setup: I have configured

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name_prefix = 'my_app_'
end
```

and changed the default PaperTrail migration to fit this:

```
def change
  create_table :my_app_foo_versions, ...
  ...
end
```

The Models are defined like this:

```
# lib/bar/baz/foo.rb
module Bar
  module Baz
    class Foo < ApplicationRecord
      has_paper_trail class_name: 'FooVersions'
    end
  end
end

# lib/bar/baz/foo_version.rb
module Bar
  module Baz
    class FooVersion < PaperTrail::Version
      self.table_name = :foo_versions
      self.sequence_name = :foo_versions_id_seq
    end
  end
end
```

In addition, the `PaperTrail::Version` is defined like so:

```
# app/models/paper_trail/versions.rb
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ApplicationRecord
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
    self.abstract_class = true
  end
end
```

Now, the migrations run without any errors, but when I create a new DB entry of `Foo` I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Bar::Baz::Foo::FooVersions
```

I have tried any naming combination I could think of (regarding file and class names), but I can't seem to get around this error. What part of this setup do I have to change to use this custom versions table for my model?

Comment: Try `has_paper_trail class_name: ::Bar::Baz::FooVersion` or `has_paper_trail class_name: 'FooVersion'` (you have plural in your example).

Comment: @Kris Removing the plural results in an undefined table error, since it relates to `foo_versions`.

Comment: Is this not a better error because at least it is finding the class. Does "foo_versions" table exist?

Comment: @Kris The table is called `my_app_foo_versions` using the `table_name_prefix` from the ApplicationRecord

Comment: But you are setting `table_name` to `:foo_versions`, sounds like you might need to include the prefix.

Comment: @Kris That was the first thing I've tried. I've also tried adding `self.table_name_prefix = 'my_app_'` to `PaperTrail::Version`, but still no luck.